# How to save array of strings in MongoDB and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For example, I have two models eg. User and Category. I have to store all the category ids which a user has liked. Users can like multiple categories.

For this,

**Method 1:**
Simply I can store an array of category id in the User model. $push method will be used when the user will like a category and the $pull method will be used when disliking that category.

**Method 2:**
I will manage all the liked categories in separate Document. I will add and remove the entry on like or unlike action. If I go with this method, how can get to know that this category is liked by the current user?

Please suggest a good way to do this.

Note:

- Data size is medium.
- Need to keep only liked categories per user.

Thanks !!

Comment: How much is medium? 5? 10? 100? 1000?

Comment: Up to 1K (strings)